# AZURE Terraform Service Principal authentication Error

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-resource-group

I am trying to authenticate azure by using a service principle and a client secret using terraform scripts.

This my main.tf file

```
# Configure the Azure provider
provider "azuread" {
  version = "~>0.8"
}

provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id = "mysubscription_id"
  client_id       = "myclient_id"
  client_secret   = "myclient_secret"
  tenant_id       = "mytenant_id"
  version         = "2.0.0"
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "aks-resource-group"
  location = "West Europe"
}
```

But error comes like this

```
│ Error: Error building account: Error getting authenticated object ID: Error listing Service Principals: autorest.DetailedError{Original:adal.tokenRefreshError{message:"adal: Refresh request failed. Status Code = '401'. Response body: {\"error\":\"invalid_client\",\"error_description\":\"AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret is provided.\\r\\nTrace ID: 4f5e5cf8-0892-4d5e-8ac7-7646d91c2d00\\r\\nCorrelation ID: 5b25c027-0a8f-4c2f-a5d0-05a169afde02\\r\\nTimestamp: 2021-09-16 12:01:26Z\",\"error_codes\":[7000215],\"timestamp\":\"2021-09-16 12:01:26Z\",\"trace_id\":\"4f5e5cf8-0892-4d5e-8ac7-7646d91c2d00\",\"correlation_id\":\"5b25c027-0a8f-4c2f-a5d0-05a169afde02\",\"error_uri\":\"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=7000215\"}", resp:(*http.Response)(0xc0007aa000)}, PackageType:"azure.BearerAuthorizer", Method:"WithAuthorization", StatusCode:401, Message:"Failed to refresh the Token for request to https://graph.windows.net/9ff0ada9-0070-48c3-bbdf-2655fe1387e6/servicePrincipals?%24filter=appId+eq+%278a10de4a-2cf6-42f6-91ca-7fc93ce89a5b%27&api-version=1.6", ServiceError:[]uint8(nil), Response:(*http.Response)(0xc0007aa000)}
│
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm"],
│   on main.tf line 6, in provider "azurerm":
│    6: provider "azurerm" {
```

My locally installed terraform version is `Terraform v1.0.5`. My local azure version is

```
{
  "azure-cli": "2.27.2",
  "azure-cli-core": "2.27.2",
  "azure-cli-telemetry": "1.0.6",
  "extensions": {}
}
```

what is the reason for that

Comment: You have error "Invalid client secret is provided". Did you check if client_secret is correct?

Comment: Invalid client_secret mean?

Comment: Please first check if the value of client_secret in Terraform code is valid. See here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/370508/getting-34invalid-client-secret-is-provided34-erro.html

Comment: @AndriyBilous Actually this  was the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you have an error "Invalid client secret is provided".

Make sure you are using client secret value and not the client secret ID in Terraform code.

```
provider "azurerm" {
  client_secret   = "..."
}
```

[image]

Or try to create a new client secret and see if that works.

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/370508/getting-34invalid-client-secret-is-provided34-erro.html

Answer (score 1):

Another solution for this is create a service principal using CLI command: `az ad sp create-for-rbac --sdk-auth` after setting in which subscription you want to create it to be used by terraform using this command: `az account set -s your subID`.

So as an output you will get all the details that needs to be used in terraform.

[image]

As per the above information received , you can use the details as shown below in the script:

```
provider "azuread" {

}

provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id = "948d4068-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx"
  client_id       = "de461fde-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx"
  client_secret   = "ThZZqKQ7wxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  tenant_id       = "72f988bf--xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx"
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "aks-resource-group"
  location = "West Europe"
}
```